# Proving that a linear map is a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve #3 in the PDF below
http://www.csun.edu/~panferov/math462_su11/m462_mt2_su11_s.pdf

It says "Let V be a finite dimensional vector space and $T: V\to V$ a linear map. If $rank (T) = rank(T^2)$, then $V = Ker(T) \oplus Im(T)$.

I'm not quite following the logic in step 3. I don't disagree with anything on the page, but I'm not sure applying the rank-nullity does in proving that it's a direct sum.

Thank you

Comment: Can you see that if $A$ and $B$ as subspaces of $V$ with $A\cap B=0$ and $\dim A + \dim B = \dim V$ then $V=A \oplus B$?

Comment: IF dimA + dimB = dimV, then does $V = A \oplus B$ by some kind of theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z\in V$. Write $z=(z-T(z))+T(z)$ and see that $z-T(z)\in kerT$ because $f(z-T(z))=T(z)-T^2(z)=0$ and thus $V\subset {kerT+imT}$ .So $V=kerT+imT$.

Now let $a\in {kerT\cap imT}$. Then $T(a)=0$ and $a=T(b)$ for some $b\in V$.  We have $0=T(a)=T^2(b)=T(b)=a$ and thus $kerT\cap imT$={$0$}.  So $V = Ker(T) \oplus Im(T)$